# Initializing a char array with values in C cause Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, arrays, char, segmentation-fault

I have an array of `char` defined as followed

```
char users[5] = "";
```

I then add users to this array by assignment as follow

```
users[0] = "UserOne";
users[1] = "UserTwo";
```

However, my program crashes with a `Segmentation Fault`.

I have looked this up online and it seems to be memory related. I tried to search for a post talking about allocating memory and have found `malloc`. However, I am a little confused with the `malloc` function.

I have tried to allocate memory to my char array using

```
users = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `users[0] = "UserOne";` is an error. Your compiler should report something for this line. If not then you need to figure out how to turn up your compiler's warning level.

Comment: You'd do well to read a book about introductory C concepts

Answer (score 0):

A char is a single character.

```
char* user[5];
```

would be the right way to create an array of pointers to char arrays(strings).

I don't know the purpose of the `= ""` in the user declaration, but it should be an error. You could do

```
char* user[5] = { "", "userOne", "userTwo", "", "" };
```

Answer (score 0):

`char users[5]` declares array of `char` objects. `"UserOne"` is an array of `char`s. `users[0] = "UserOne";` tries to assign an array of `char`s to a single `char`. You may not do that.

You should do something like the following:

```
char* users[5];
user[0] = malloc(8 * sizeof(char)); /* Allocate memory for storing the data, 8 - is the size of "UserOne" */
if(user[0] != NULL)                 /* Test that the allocation succeeded */
    strcpy(user[0], "UserOne");     /* Store the data */
```

Please note that this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array of char defined as followed
>
> ```
> char users[5] = "";
> ```

(there is nothing wrong with this declaration. It properly initializes each of the five characters to `0`)

> I then add users to this array by assignment as follow
>
> ```
> users[0] = "UserOne";
> users[1] = "UserTwo";
> ```
>
> However, my program crashes with a Segmentation Fault. (***You
>   think?***)

What makes you think you can store a *pointer to a string literal* (which is `8-char` on x86_64 and `4-char` on x86) as a **single character** in `users[0]`? The same applies to `users[1]`.

When you declare `char users[5] = "";` you have created an *array of char*, e.g. that has 5 **character** indexes available for use, e.g.:

```
-----------
|0|1|2|3|4|
-----------
```

What it appears you intended to do was to created an *array of pointer to char*, e.g.

```
char *users[5] = {NULL};
```

Now, with an array of pointers, you can assign the beginning address of each of your *string literals* to the `users` array, e.g.

```
users[0] = "UserOne";
users[1] = "UserTwo";
...
users[4] = "LastOneYouCanAdd";
```

Think it though and let me know if you have any further questions. A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXU 5

int main (void) {

    char *users[MAXU] = {NULL};
    users[0] = "UserOne";
    users[1] = "UserTwo";
    users[4] = "Straggler";

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXU; i++)
        if (users[i])
            printf (" users[%d] : %s\n", i, users[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/usersptr
 users[0] : UserOne
 users[1] : UserTwo
 users[4] : Straggler
```

(*note:* initialization of the pointers in `users` to `NULL` is required to be able to iterate over and test whether a pointer has been assigned in the example above)